# Why is the usage of a character's name not always trademark infringement?

Tags: naming, trademark

In most cases, using a character's name from a fictional universe is not a trademark infringement (unless the character is being reused, that would be a copyright infringement). Why does this happen?

Comment: I don't have the legal background in trademark law to write a full answer, but the extremely short and oversimplified version is this: Trademarks are about consumer confusion. No confusion, no problem - in theory. In practice, it's much more complicated than that because you also have to consider dilution and other "indirect" causes of confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Names of Characters Copyrighted by Authors?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/291/are-names-of-characters-copyrighted-by-authors)

Comment: Copyright and Trademark are two unrelated things.  Which are you asking about?

Comment: @Chenmunka About trademark specifically.

Comment: Trademarks must be registered in every relevant jurisdiction.  Simply check with the authorities.

Comment: If a fictional character becomes a cultural icon, then mentioning them becomes a form of social commentary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a trademark has to be registered with an authority, such as the [US Patent and Trademark Office](https://www.uspto.gov/), to be recognized as such. One does not automatically gain trademark protection, it has to be obtained by applying for one. Which is not automatically approved, by the way.

Second, even if a name is trademarked, a trademark does not work the same was as copyright. Trademarks are mostly about [protecting your brand](https://www.uspto.gov/trademarks/basics/what-trademark), that is, ensuring the public knows a particular name or image is associated with you, or your company, and not a competitor or imitator. It's not really concerned with preventing other people from using the same name, or image, just using it in a way that would "confuse the public" in regards to authenticity or origin of it.